# Do this expression makes sense?

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

I was studying polarization, a subject from electromagnetism/optics. When we talk about the polarization of the electric field, some expression as $\vec{E} = Ae^{-iwt}(\vec{x} + i\vec{y})$ can arise. For those who don't know, this basically represents, if we talk mathematically, a vector rotating on the $xy$ plane. And this last statement i wrote is where i confuse myself.

In physics we need to take the real part of the whole expression to get the real field. But thinking about the object $Ae^{-iwt}(\vec{x} + i\vec{y})$, i asked myself if it has a meaning.

Now, $Ae^{-iwt}(\vec{x} + i\vec{y})=Ae^{-iwt}(\vec{x} + e^{i\pi/2}\vec{y})$. How do i represent it as vector rotating without taking the real part? Is it possible? I mean, i thought to represent it in the complex plane, just as $\vec{v} = x\vec{x} + y\vec{y}$ can be represented in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane. BUT, using this analogy, $y = xe^{i\pi/2}$ and this does not rotate at all. So, basically, does the expression has a meaning without taking the real part? or at least a geometrical meaning? Can it be represented as arrows?

Comment: The field $\vec{E} = Ae^{-iwt}(\vec{x} + i\vec{y})$ you wrote cannot exist, as it is a complex electric field, just check with $e^{-i w t} = {\rm{cos}} (w t) - i {\, \rm{sin}} (w t)$, that gives two real terms and two imaginary terms, and so you are missing a part of the field.